# jqgrid date sorting and formatting

Tags: sorting, date, jqgrid, formatting

I need to display date in two formats like mm/dd/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss. I found we can use formatoptions in colmodel

```
formatoptions: {srcformat: 'ISO8601Long', newformat: 'm/d/y'}
```

and

```
formatoptions: {srcformat: 'ISO8601Long', newformat: 'm/d/y h:i:s'}
```

but i am getting output in jqgrid as mm/dd/yy. Shall any one give solution how to display mm/dd/yyyy. I need to do sorting for both columns.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use 'Y' instead of 'y' to display the year as 'yyyy' instead of 'yy':

```
formatter:'date', formatoptions: {srcformat:'ISO8601Long', newformat:'m/d/Y H:i:s'}
```

If you want to have no preceding nulls (without 0 padding) in the mounth and tha da you can use 'n/j/Y' instead of 'm/d/Y'. All different possible flags supported by the 'date' formatter you can find in [the source code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.1/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L206) of the formatter.

**UPDATED**: The problem is that the short names of the `srcformat` like `ISO8601Long`, `UniversalSortableDateTime`, `ShortDate` and so on (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter#language_options) for details) can be used only with **the remote grid data** (`datatype:'json'` or `datatype:xml`). To make local sorting work correct you should use instead of `srcformat:'ISO8601Long'` to `srcformat:'Y-m-d H:i:s'`.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithISO8601Long.htm) shows that such change will make local sorting works correct.

I think that the restriction in `srcformat` could be interpret as a bug in jqGrid. So I recommend you to post the corresponding bug report in [the trirand forum](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/). Then Tony Tomov (the developer of jqGrid) could make the corresponding changes in the jqGrid code.

Comment: thanx oleg, but sorting is not hapenning. my colmodel code is '{name:'invdate',index:'invdate',sorttype:'date', formatter:'date', formatoptions: {srcformat: 'ISO8601Long', newformat: 'm/d/Y'} },' and my array data is '{id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test"}'. Do I miss any properties?

Comment: @user669789: Now I understand your main problem and suggest you to use `srcformat:'Y-m-d H:i:s'` instead of `srcformat:'ISO8601Long'` as a workaround. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Many many thanks....I tried to bind jqgrid with remote data(json format) and I wanted to display the date format as dd/mm/yyyy. after using the below options

formatter:'date', formatoptions: {srcformat:'ISO8601Long', newformat:'d/m/Y'}

It's working perfectly.