# Where do I specify Jackson SerializationConfig.Feature settings in Spring 3.1

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm puzzled as to why using a default inclusion of jackson that Spring seems to have customised the default Jackson configuration.

One setting it's messing with is `WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS`, the [Jackson default](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeaturesSerialization) is `true` however Spring has somewhere changed this to `false` and also provided a date format.

Where in the world is this happening? I want my dates to remain serialised as numbers.

**UPDATE**: Turns out it's not spring that's causing the problem, it's actually hibernates proxy classes causing the problem. For some reason if hibernate has a type-mapping of `type="date"` it serialises as a date string, though if its `type="timestamp"` it serialises as expected. Rather than spend too much time looking into this I've decided to just change all my mappings to timestamp for now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Starting with 3.1 M1 you can specify jackson custom configuration by registering an `HttpMessageConverters` through a sub-element of `mvc:annotation-driven`.

See [Spring 3.1 MVC Namespace Improvements](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/21/spring-3-1-m1-mvc-namespace-enhancements-and-configuration/)

See [SPR-7504](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7504?focusedCommentId=62730&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel) Make it easier to add new Message Converters to AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter

Exemple:

```
<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="x.y.z.CustomObjectMapper">                
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
       <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
           <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
       </bean>
       </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

The CustomObjectMapper Object

```
    @Component("jacksonObjectMapper")
    public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

        @PostConstruct
        public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {

            SerializationConfig serialConfig = getSerializationConfig()     
                        .withDateFormat(null);

                  //any other configuration

            this.setSerializationConfig(serialConfig);
        }
    }
```

> **[SerializationConfig .withDateFormat](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/SerializationConfig.html#withDateFormat%28java.text.DateFormat%29)**
>
> In addition to constructing instance with specified date format, will enable or disable 
>   Feature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS (enable if format set as null; disable if non-null)

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I'm after, though either it doesn't appear to be working for me or for some other reason Spring is choosing a different `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` instance than that of which I've created. Is there a way to identify all instances of `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` that have been created that could be getting selected?

Comment: I've confirmed that the `CustomObjectMapper` implementation is writing the correct format by simply writing a test object to a file after `this.setSerializationConfig(serialConfig);` and it's working fine, though this instance doesn't appear to be used by the `<mvc:annotation-driven>` declaration. Do I possibly need to specify an `id` for a known type?

Comment: I've found my problem. It comes down to the use of hibernate mapping of `type="date"`, changing to `type="timestamp"` resolved the issue.