# Jackson2 creates wrong date format when running on server

Tags: java, jackson

When run on Tomcat6 or Tomcat7 or WAS7, the following code is always printing out the internal `java.util.Date` property as yyyy-MM-DD format instead of millisecond format.

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println(om.writeValueAsString(myObject));
```

When running standalone, the above code prints out the correct millisecond format.

Is there anything that server could be doing to interfere? I am using Jackson 2.0.6 and Spring 3.1.2 here.

**Result:**
I found out the issue was that my Date object was getting java.sql.Date. I guess you will not get a timestamp if you're using java.sql.Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jackson serialization config may be being stepped on in a number of places including spring and/or hibernate as described here:  [Where do I specify Jackson SerializationConfig.Feature settings in Spring 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576907/where-do-i-specify-jackson-serializationconfig-feature-settings-in-spring-3-1)

There are probably more correct solutions to stop Spring/Hibernate from doing what they are doing, but if it were up to me, I would just do the following:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.setDateFormat(null);
System.out.println(om.writeValueAsString(myObject));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Result: I found out the issue was that my Date object was getting
>   java.sql.Date. I guess you will not get a timestamp if you're using
>   java.sql.Date.

Jackson is not using property WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS or format from setDateFormat in case of java.sql.Date. To make it possible need to provide special Serializer for ObjectMapper.

Something like that:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer;

public class SqlDateSerializer extends StdSerializer<java.sql.Date> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public SqlDateSerializer() {
        super(java.sql.Date.class, true);
    }

    private ThreadLocal<DateFormat> DATE_FORMAT 
        = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() 
           -> new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"));

    @Override
    public void serialize(java.sql.Date value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {

        String formatted = DATE_FORMAT.get().format(value);
        gen.writeString(formatted);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
simpleModule.addSerializer(java.sql.Date.class, new SqlDateSerializer());

ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.registerModule(simpleModule);
```