# Why jackson formats date to yyyy-MM-dd instead of timestamp?

Tags: json, spring, maven, spring-mvc, jackson

I have my first spring project with a rest service.
Only one problem I cannot solve myself. My "get" request gives the objects date value this way:

```
{"id":6,"type":"Trainer","changed":"2015-06-20","created":"2015-06-19"}
```

but I want it in timestamp format, as I thought was the default.

The input dates in my PUT request are parsed from timestamp format as expected.

I am using springframework 4.1.6.RELEASE and fasterxml.jackson 2.5.4
with these spring artifacts: spring-context, spring-webmvc, spring-jdbc

and these fasterxml artifacts: jackson-core, jackson-databind

This is my Controller method:

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public T getObject(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    T obj = dao.getById(id);
    logger.debug("GET " + getClass().getSimpleName() + "." + id + ": " + obj);
    return obj;
}
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml 

    version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        version="2.5">
        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
            </param-value>
        </context-param>
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>
                    /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml
                    classpath:Beans.xml
                </param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="de.kreth.clubhelperbackend" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="2" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

and my Beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/clubhelperbackend" />
        <property name="username" value="markus" />
        <property name="password" value="0773" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlForDialect" class="de.kreth.clubhelperbackend.SqlForMysql">
        <constructor-arg ref="jdbcTemplate" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="personDao" class="de.kreth.clubhelperbackend.dao.PersonDao">
        <property name="sqlDialect" ref="sqlForDialect" />
        <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dbcheckAspect" class="de.kreth.clubhelperbackend.aspects.MysqlDbCheckAspect">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

<!--    <bean id="logger" class="de.kreth.clubhelperbackend.aspects.LoggerAspect" /> -->

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
        <aop:include name="dbcheckAspect" />
<!--        <aop:include name="logger"/> -->
    </aop:aspectj-autoproxy>

</beans>
```

So, how can I get the json date output in general as a timestamp?

Please note, that I don't want to change the data classes (getters) as they are generated from another project.

--- Edit:
The Person Model:

```
public class Person implements java.io.Serializable, Data  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2810735258874241724L;
    private Long id;
    private String type;

    /** Not-null value. */
    private java.util.Date changed;
    /** Not-null value. */
    private java.util.Date created;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Person(Long id, String type,java.util.Date changed, java.util.Date created) {
        this.id = id;
        this.type = type;
        this.changed = changed;
        this.created = created;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    /** Not-null value. */
    public java.util.Date getChanged() {
        return changed;
    }

    /** Not-null value; ensure this value is available before it is saved to the database. */
    public void setChanged(java.util.Date changed) {
        this.changed = changed;
    }

    /** Not-null value. */
    public java.util.Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }
}
```

The date interface:

```
package de.kreth.clubhelperbackend.pojo;
import java.util.Date;

public interface Data {
    public Long getId() ;
    public void setId(Long id);
    public Date getChanged();
    public void setChanged(Date changed);
    public Date getCreated();
    public void setCreated(Date created);
}
```

Comment: How would it know what timezone the date is meant to be in?

Comment: @SkinnyJ: I don't understand your question.  Unix timestamp is always GMT I think. And the Date objects have local Timezone, no need for GregorianCalendar.

Comment: Please show your model. Usually you have to specify `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Date dateField` to get this style of output.

Comment: My point is that a yyyy-MM-dd is logically ambiguous as to the moment in time that it represents (if any). Converting it to the Date representing midnight on that date in GMT is making quite a few assumptions. I don't know about Jackson, but that would be my question for anyone who wants to represent a LocalDate as an instant in time.

Comment: I changed Data and Person to use Calendar instead of Date. Then the output is in timestamp, but the input doesn't work anymore giving this message: The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.

Answer (score 0):

[According Jackson docs](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Serialization-features#datatype-specific-serialization), Jackson should use timestamps in miliseconds by default.

So I see two options. One is that your date format is enforced by `@JsonFormat` annotation on your date field as @beerbajay mentioned in his comment.

Second option is that somebody configured custom `ObjectMapper` for your `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter`. Such example configuration is in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9708525/1919879). I would try to find it in your application and talk to the teammate that introduced it why it's needed.

If such custom ObjectMapper isn't configured, it's strange, but at least you can try to explicitly configure SerializationConfig.getDateFormat as WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS to true.

Comment: Well, there are no @JsonFormat annotations anywhere and there is no custom ObjectMapper. As its my personal TestProject, there is nobody to ask. I used to generate the project structure by eclipse's Spring MVC Project wizard.

Comment: Spring 4.1 btw Jackson 2.5.4 doesn't know SerializationConfig.Feature WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS !?

Comment: JSonFormat is Jackson annotation. You will need Jackson dependency

Answer (score 0):

I think Jackson treats `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` differently. Even though the later is actually a subclass of the former, Jackson assumes both classes are totally different.

So, if you don't want the value to be converted to 'yyyy-MM-dd', ensure that it is not a `java.sql.Date` object.

For example:

```
class Student {
   private java.util.Date birthDate;

   // getter and setter
}

Student san = new Student();

// Then JSON converted to: 'yyyy-MM-dd' format
san.setBirthDate(new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

// Then JSON converted to: timestamp format or according to @JsonFormat format
san.setBirthDate(new java.util.Date());
```