# Format time in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to set format for time in a jqGrid. It does not work. I would like to use the predefined formatter in the locale-file. This is how the col is defined:

```
          { name: 'Tid', index: 'Tid', width: 65, editable: true, formatoptions: { mask: 'ShortTime' }, editrules: { time: true} }
```

I have tried a few different alternatives, but it does not seem to make a differnce in the grid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation seems to me not clear enough. The correct syntax should be

```
formatoptions: { srcformat: 'ISO8601Long', newformat: 'ShortTime' }
```

Additional problem is: default value of `srcformat` defined in `$.jgrid.formatter.date.srcformat` (in `grid.locale-en.js`): 'Y-m-d'. So any time information from the input data will be ignored by default.

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/TimeFormat.htm).

If you want use local data in the grid, you should additionally take in the consideration the bug which I reported [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/errors-in-parsedate-method-with-f-m-and-j-formats/#p25721). The bug is [fixed](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/b688200d8c25a1d639b94b802d47653798da34e1) in the code on the github, but it was after publishing of jqGrid 4.3.1.

Comment: Thanks! I've changed the col to this: { name: 'Tid', index: 'Tid', width: 65, editable: true, formatoptions: { newformat: 'ShortTime' }, editrules: { time: true} } , but it does not seem to make any difference. It it correct?

Comment: @kaze: Do you defined `srcformat` correctly? Probably [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/TimeFormat.htm) will help you to understand the reason of your problem.

Comment: As usual, gold quality answer and example. Problem solved. It was the srcformat (also)!

Comment: @kaze: You are welcome! I'll change the text of my answer to include  `srcformat` inside. Probably other people would have the same problem: default value of `srcformat` corresponds to `ShortDate` format and so the time will be ignored by default.