# Outputting SQL time datatype in jqgrid

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

Can't figure out how to display a SQL time datatype column into my jqgrid using the "formatter" property or else.

It works for dates as follow:

formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'd/m/Y', newformat: 'd/m/Y'}

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the Format function and return the string

```
Declare @Time time = getdate()
Select Original=@Time,Formatted=format(cast(@Time as datetime),'hh:mm:ss')
```

Returns

```
Original            Formatted
11:16:58.2530000    11:16:58
```

There is another option, but it looks rather involved for me.
[Format time in jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10010595/format-time-in-jqgrid)