# Sort a date column in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I am using [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=start) for displaying records in a user interface, and I want to sort the date column. Which returns me the date in the form of `Sat, Sep 1, 01:41 AM`. How can I do that with jqGrid?

My Colmodel for that column is:

```
{name:'transactiontime', index:'transactiontime',  sorttype:'text', align:"right"},
```

Comment: did you try looking at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4545917/549643?

Comment: But what should be the format of the formatter vale

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following `formatoptions`:

```
{name: 'transactiontime', sorttype: 'date', align: "right", formatter: 'date',
    formatoptions: {srcformat: 'ISO8601Long', newformat: 'D, M d, H:i A'}}
```

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/simplelocalgridwithiso8601long1.htm) which is a simple modification of the demo from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6477167/315935).

The `srcformat` could depend on the input format of your data.

Comment: What is `ISO8601Long` format and how to pass that value from server side ?

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: `ISO8601Long` is the same as `"Y-m-d H:i:s"` (see [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js#L114)). It's [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format which includes the time information. Examples from my demo: `"2007-10-01T16:48:14"` and `"2007-10-01T16:47"`. One can use `2012-09-17T09:49Z` to specify UTC time

Comment: What if I want to sort the values like `750.46 KB` or `750.46 MB` etc. ? Please respond as soon as possible.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: I don't like if one write me "respond as soon as possible". I am now in another country at the customer who pay me for the consulting work which I do (no relation with jqGrid). So I can't make support other people over the world. Nevertheless what you need is probably implementing of **custom sorting**: the usage `sorttype` as function. See the demo from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5296935/315935).

Comment: Still please responde to my question if possible.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: I answered already in the previous comment: you can implements *custom sorting* for the column having 750.46 KB: see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5296935/315935). In the demo from the answer the `parseInt` will be called to parse the integer part of the value. You can convert `750.46 KB` or `750.46 MB` in the same way to the number which represent **bytes** and return the number from `sorttype` function.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: I'm busy now. I think you can write yourself the JavaScript code which convert the string `"750.46 KB"` to the number `76847104` (`750.46*1024`) and which comvert the string `"750.46 MB"` to the number `78691434496` (`750.46*1024*1024`).

Comment: My problem is just related with sorting of the values in the JQgrid.

Comment: One more thing is that the `newformat: 'D, M d, H:i A'}` is not working with chrome. It displays ambiguous format of dates.

Comment: Hi, I am formatting date, which has Day Name and date like , Wed, 01-03-2017, But some how it behave weird, I have saved the fiddle please have a look http://jsfiddle.net/alpeshjikadra/jss5b43j/1/

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra: You should post **separate** question, where you describe detailed the problem. You should mention, which version of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which fork of jqGrid: [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sorttype:'date'` and datefmt:

`datefmt` governs the format of `sorttype:date` (when datetype is set to local) and editrules {date:true} fields. It determines the expected date format for that column and uses a PHP-like date formatting. Currently ”/”, ”-”, and ”.” are supported as date separators. Valid formats are:

- y,Y,yyyy for four digits year
- YY, yy for two digits year
- m,mm for months
- d,dd for days.

Of course, you can sort on server side too, if it is more painless. You can use the `sidx` and `sord` fields on server side.